# How to set up my sqlite database in my maven proejct?

Tags: java, sqlite

I put my database under the "src/main/resources/database" directory, so the relative path is:

```
database/ExtraInfo.db
```

My full path in creating the URL is :

```
String url =  "jdbc:sqlite:/Users/cong/service/src/main/resources/database/ExtraInfo.db";
```

This works for the the absolute the path. However, I need to use a relative path to be able to run it on other computers. I tried the following, it doesn't work:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + "/database/ExtraInfo.db";
```

Error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: path to '/database/ExtraInfo.db': '/database' does not exist
```

How to use the relative path to make it work in my standard Maven project?

Comment: don't use `/` at the beginning - it means absolute path from the root

Comment: @llya Got a new exacption: java.sql.SQLException: path to 'database/ExtraInfo.0403.db': '/Users/cong/service/database' does not exist

Comment: then use `src/main/resources/database/ExtraInfo.db`

Comment: jdbc:sqlite/src/main/resources/database/ExtraInfo.db: java.sql.SQLException: invalid database address: jdbc:sqlite/src/main/resources/database/ExtraInfo.db

Comment: forgot `:` between sqlite and path

Comment: "/Users/cong/service/src/" does not exist with "jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/database/ExtraInfo.db".